# Custom button adding items to cart

Tags: pwa, venia, react, pdp, react-js

We created New **custom button** below **Buy now** button in PDP Page.

**Issue** :

But when we click on that custom button, it's adding the  items to cart. But We did not linked any code for that custom button.

**Requirement** : Button should be unclickable.

[Here is Website link](https://frontend1.staging.glowjewels.com/dreamy-wonder-diamond-necklace)

Here is Full code **ProductFullDetail.js** : https://pastebin.com/PqWJxZgj

```
{cartActionContent}

                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                  <WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} />
                </Suspense>

                <button className="custom-button-web">Custom Button</button>
              </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have made changes to your code please replace all your code from this code and I think this will work - https://pastebin.com/EwPrPBvU

Comment: Thanks for the code, but i think some syntax error is there. so page is not loading,  i am also checking, if you get any idea, please give updated code

Comment: i got this error in website :  `Sorry! An unexpected error occurred. Debug: ReferenceError53F at xt (/RootCmp_PRODUCT__default.a6bc616c21dd794cbdd6.js:149:182`

Comment: Okay so replace your previous code I have just 2 changes to the file add this const before return - https://prnt.sc/sDzHgjaX_48F and replace the old button code with this please change this changes only - https://prnt.sc/uKybqg_giFbN

Comment: @RohitGohel , yes i done the same. also you also added only those code.  i also checked in https://www.diffchecker.com/ ,  there is no syntax error in your code. i will recheck tomorow again. thankyou